# Having trouble with psql \copy command

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm a postrgresql noob. I'm using psql on a remote server. I've made a query that I'd like to download as a csv. The query runs just fine on its own.

There are two tables involved in the query. The first:

```
CREATE TABLE players (username varchar(100), skill varchar(100),id int);
INSERT INTO players VALUES
('user1', 'flight', 1),
('user2', 'run', 2),
('user3', 'run', 3),
('user4', 'flight', 4),
('user5', 'flight', 5),
('user6', 'climb', 6),
('user7', 'flight', 7),
('user8', 'flight', 8),
('user9', 'flight', 9),
('user10', 'climb', 10);
```

The second table is temporary, I only need it to exist to extract this csv:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE specific_players (username varchar(100));
INSERT INTO specific_players VALUES
('user2'),
('user5'),
('user7'),
('user9');
```

my query looks like this:

```
select * from players p inner join specific_players sp USING (username);
```

Like I said, that works just fine.
But when I try to wrap it in a copy command

```
\copy (select * from players inner join specific_players USING (username)) to '/Users/me/path/to/folder/filename.csv' with csv
```

I get an error:

```
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
    LINE 1: COPY  ( select * from players p join specific_playe...
```

The file IS created on my computer, but it's empty. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It is working in my psql (result is file with 4 lines) - what is version of your psql?

Comment: 8.0.2 .. really - It is pretty old unsupported release - probably it has not implemented this feature. Please, do upgrade.

Comment: ah, okay--that helps